# SetupSequence moq for different file string paths C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have 2 different file paths which I read 'last write time':

```
var current1TimeStamp = File.GetLastWriteTime(path)(file1);
var current2TimeStamp = File.GetLastWriteTime(path)(file2);
```

I want to setup a mock sequence but I have a problem:

```
var fileServiceMock = new Mock<IFile>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            fileServiceMock.SetupSequence(s => s.GetLastWriteTime())
                .Returns(System.DateTime.Now)
                .Returns(System.DateTime.Now);
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to mock the static method `System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime`? Moq cannot help you with that

Comment: You have not stated the problem

Comment: @JonasHøgh - Actually I moq another file service that is not static. That was just example. I think I have a problem inside the `s => s.GetLastWriteTime()`

Comment: You should include the declaration of the method you're trying to mock. It looks like you're missing the parameters in the mock setup call. Have you tried something like `s => s.GetLastWriteTime(It.IsAny<string>())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, you should provide values for the parameters of the mocked method inside the lambda expression. If you do not care about the values passed, you can use the method `It.IsAny<T>()`

```
var fileServiceMock = new Mock<IFile>(MockBehavior.Strict);
fileServiceMock.SetupSequence(s => s.GetLastWriteTime(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(System.DateTime.Now)
    .Returns(System.DateTime.Now);
```

Your current setup will return the same value (possibly give or take a microsecond) for the first two calls to the mocked method. Maybe it would be better to use `Setup` instead of `SetupSequence` since you don't really care about the number of calls here? Or you could set up different return values based on the path input, as follows:

```
var fileServiceMock = new Mock<IFile>(MockBehavior.Strict);
fileServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLastWriteTime("path/to/file1"))
  .Returns(someDateTime);
fileServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetLastWriteTime("path/to/file2"))
  .Returns(someOtherDateTime);
```